# jni call involving open cobol dlls

Tags: gcc, java-native-interface, static-linking, cobol, gnucobol

I am trying to invoke an existing COBOL application using JNI. COBOL application structure is as follows.

```
c-wrapper(main)-->COBOLProgram -> several dyn(.so) and static  called modules
```

The existing COBOL application involves several statically called subprograms(COBOL) and many dynamic(COBOL) ones.

Jni invocation of the application is ok, but it could not locate and invoke COBOL dynamic sub modules.

Modified Application structure  (for jni) is as follows:

```
java class --> libjni.so --> appl.so
```

I verified COB_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables before the CALL, those seems to be fine.

Following error message got in the case dynamic modules.

```
libcob:  ....<module>.so: undefined symbol: cob_save_call_params
```

I use 64 bit , 1.1.0 on linux. gcc is used to create binary using the c output of cobc command

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH must only point to libcob and the so-files needed by it. COB_LIBRARY_PATH should have all COBOL modules in.
What do they look like?
Are you sure that you use the same architecture (32/64 bit) for both the java runtime and libcob and the application files? What is the exact error you get? What version of OpenCOBOL do you use?

Comment: Updated the question using error message and OC version. I used on exception after the call, so the error was not shown.

Comment: OK, therefore the problem isn't in the called modules but in one of the symbols of libcob itself. Does it help to force the module load (must done **before** starting Java) by `export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libcob.so`?
BTW: "linux" isn't very specific ;-) Side question: [sorry for polluting the question] does this happen with [a GnuCOBOL 2.0 dev snapshot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/files/gnu-cobol/2.0/gnu-cobol-2.0_nightly_r624.tar.gz/download), too?

Comment: Does the suggested fix worked for you? I would re-post it as answer in this case...

Comment: No, I tried GNU COBOL 2.0, it is even worser

Comment: Please edit your question add the "worse" 2.0 result as additional information, too (you used OpenCOBOL 1.1, correct?).

Did the `export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libcob.so` **before** starting Java help?

Comment: No, It does not work.  I tried GNU COBOL 2.0, it is even worser, it crashes even c-->COBOL(converted to c) static linking.

Comment: At one point I could resolve the issue,when I used cobc -m option to directly build the .so file. So I guess this issue was something to do with the compiler options. The build-procedure used earlier was translating sources to c and then using gcc to create .so files. I will investigate what exactly causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be resolved by properly specifying -lcob linkage option(when using gcc). The gcc command used to create the binary already contained the option, but it was mistakenly placed in between target and source file, which was not in effect. Execution of dll without JNI invocation, somehow does not require -lcob option, but from the JNI invocation requires -lcob linkage option.